# How to remove the list of numbers after a BibTex bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'd like to remove the numbers at the end of my bibliography:

[image]

The code is

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\cite{Cottle_2009}
\cite{Bhattacharjee2015}
\cite{Wikram98}
\cite{Wikramanayake2011}
\cite{Wingfield98}
\cite{Weise2014}
\cite{Walston2010}
\cite{Trinkel2011}
```

etc with more references, followed by '\end{document}'.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The list of numbers is the result of all the `\cite` commands.  To get rid of them, just remove the `\cite`s.  What you may have in mind instead is to make sure these entries get included in your bibliography.  To do that, instead of `\cite`, use `\nocite`.  That will add them to the bibliography, but not mention them anywhere else.  If you want to include *all* the entries in your `.bib` file in the bibliography, you can say `\nocite{*}`, but if you want to ignore some of those entries, you have to be selective.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you replace

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\cite{Cottle_2009}
\cite{Bhattacharjee2015}
\cite{Wikram98}
\cite{Wikramanayake2011}
\cite{Wingfield98}
\cite{Weise2014}
\cite{Walston2010}
\cite{Trinkel2011}
```

with

```
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\nocite{Cottle_2009,Bhattacharjee2015,Wikram98,Wikramanayake2011,Wingfield98}
\nocite{Weise2014,Walston2010,Trinkel2011}
```

Note that it's perfectly alright to (a) have more than one `\nocite` instruction in the document and (b) include several entries in the argument of a `\nocite` instruction.

Any additonal publications you wish to have show up in the formatted bibliography but for which you don't want to create individual citation call-outs should also get the `\nocite` treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove individual \cite after stating bibstyle and bibliography.

Put all your references via jabref or any other literature libs. Then just call it in your code, for example: 
\bibliography{reference.bib}

assuming reference.bib contains all your rrls.
Hope this helps

Comment: Whereas, if not all references are well cited. To still display it in the references, add \nocite{*} before \bibliography{style}